# How to open Statistica *.sta file under R?

Tags: r

How to open Statistica *.sta file under R?  Is there any package for that?

Comment: do you have an .sta file you can make publicly available? The answer by Rachel below suggests a possible solution, but there's no way to test it out without a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

Download the `statconnDCOM` library at [rcom.univie.ac.at](http://rcom.univie.ac.at)

Then install the R package `rcom` (this will also install package `rscproxy` that is necessary for `statconnDCOM`).

To install, run the following commands in R console:

```
install.packages('rcom')
library(rcom)
comRegisterRegistry()
```

Comment: The foreign documentation does not list Statistica files as an option, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: This link also does not say anything about Statistica files, it does mention how to read Stata, SAS, etc, but not Statistica.

Comment: Note that you cannot install `rcom` from CRAN (not even archived version) because: `This depends on statconnDCOM, which nowadays restricts use, contrary to the CRAN policy for a package with a FOSS licence`.

Comment: What you've got here is apparently from http://www.statsoft.com/l/r-integration-with-statistica/ . That page does say "process STATISTICA data sets in R" but it's not clear whether this is possible without a running instance of Statistica (the OP doesn't make it clear whether they have Statistica or not ...)

Comment: From what I can gather you need to have Statistica running, and the package facilitates communication between them.

Comment: @RachelGallen you question is still a bit broad, in the sense that you only provide the link to being able to have Statistica and R communicating. Could you add some specific information on how to read a statistica file using `rcom`. And does `foreign` come into to play anywhere? If not, you could delete it from you answer.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra it is not my question, it is Qbik's question that i am merely trying to provide a solution to

Comment: I think @PaulHiemstra meant to say "your answer is still a bit broad"

Comment: @RachelGallen Like Ben Bolker said, you are answering Qbik's answer only in very broad terms (here is how to connect R and Statistica). An analogy might be if someone asks how to perform a linear regression in R, and answering with: "download R and open it". SO is built around collaborative answering, and I'm simply commenting that your answer is very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Did this strategy suggested by Rachel Gallen work? I was stuck with a vital dataset stored in this .sta file with seemingly no way to extract it from there except for obtaining a copy of Statistica for myself, which I didn't want to do especially if I'd have to pay big buck for it. But it turns out if you're from academia, they grant you a 12-month rent for free. https://www.onthehub.com/statistica/ Provide them with your academic e-mail and it's good to go. It's more than enough for me to convert all these pesky .sta files into more handy formats. They don't even ask for all this personal data like name, company, etc. The downside is to have to download and install 1.3 Gb of a program, when you only essentially only using it as an overqualified file converter.

**tl;dr:** if you're a scholar, you can download statistica for free and use it for 12 months