# How to Import statistica data (*.sta) into R

Tags: r, import

I'm a master student and I'm having a course in statistics with the program STATISTICA. I am rather familiar with R and would like to stick to it. So I am planning to do the provided exercises in R. However the data to work with is in the format *.sta... is there a way to import such a file into R? Any workaround is also fine, as long as it doesn't compromise the data.

I actually found the same question 2 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523674/how-to-open-statistica-sta-file-under-r) but there was no answer to it.

I'd be very happy for any suggestions!

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: My first impulse would be to look at the [`foreign`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/foreign.pdf) package, which does not mention Statistica any more than it did two years ago. It doesn't look good for you. Perhaps you could talk to your instructor and ask him to provide the data in csv or txt (one argument being that then Statistica users would also learn importing these data). Failing that, it may be best just to do this course in Statistica - knowing multiple tools is a valuable skill, after all.

Comment: Have you tried saving the data as a .csv file in Statistica and then using `read.csv` in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If R does not support importing Statistica Spreadsheet files (.sta files), Statistica supports exporting data to .xlsx, .csv, and SPSS and SAS format files. I would think that one of those would be able to be handled by R natively.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Statistica-R integration through Statistica, a package called COMadaptR will be installed to R.

Once that is done, you have a couple of options:

- You can run your R script inside of Statistica using the extensions (provided by Statistica) ActiveDataSet or Spreadsheet to access the Statistica spreadsheet as an R data frame.
- You can create an R node in a workspace; connect the Statistica spreadsheet to the R node in the workspace; and then run your R script through the node. ActiveDataSet and Spreadsheet will be available in the R node context as well.
- You could write a small R script (and use ActiveDataSet or Spreadsheet) and run it in Statistica; the R integration features will translate the Statistica spreadsheet to an R data frame. You could then in your script store it to disk and work with it later.
- The COMadaptR package will allow you to interact with Statistica through COM from within R; you could use that approach to read data from the Statistica spreadsheet.

Hope this helps.